# Kerberos Timestamp Evaluation

Tags: security, kerberos

When a user is logging on to a computer joined to a domain, or when a client is sending a request to a service within the same domain, in both cases, the Kerberos documentation says:

> The KDC decrypts the pre-authentication data and evaluates the timestamp inside. If the timestamp passes the test, the KDC can be assured that the pre-authentication data was encrypted with the user key and thus verify that the user is genuine.
>
> The service uses the session key to decrypt the user's authenticator and then evaluates the timestamp inside. If the authenticator passes the test, the service looks for a mutual authentication flag in the client's request.

Can somebody please explain to me how do the KDC and the Service "evaluate" the timestamp? And how does evaluating the timestamp relate to verifying the user's identity?

P.S: I'm quoting from [How the Kerberos Version 5 Authentication Protocol Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772815%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pre-authentication message the server receives the current timestamp encrypted with the current session key (or the key derived from the users password).

So the server tries to decrypt this message using the session key, and if the result is a timestamp that's within the given time-window, then the server can be sure that the encryption has been done by someone knowing the correct key: when the encryption has been done using the wrong key, then the decrypted timestamp would usually be way off from the current time.

Comment: Sorry; this is wrong. This explanation says that the KDC tells whether the timestamp was encrypted with the right key (derived from the user's password), by whether the timestamp looks right, i.e. indicates  a recent time. That is, it says that no matter what key the message was encrypted with, it will decrypt successfully to some timestamp, but the timestamp will usually be wildly off if the key is wrong. This is not what happens at all. All Kerberos encrypted messages have integrity checking built in; if the key is wrong, decryption *fails*, period. The timestamp serves a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Data must arrive within a given timeframe, if not it gets discarded. Look for "Clock skew too great".